# Android In-app Subscription expiry check and testing

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

I have an android app that have subscriptions. I want to do some ui change when subscription expires.

```
if( subscription expires )
   //do something
```

Q1) how do i handle the above in code? I'm using TrivialDrive Sample app classes for In-app. And where should i handle this check in code?

Q2) reserved key words are not working for subscription testing. Do I have to use actual credit card for testing subscriptions? My app is unpublished, product activated and apk signed.

Answer (score 4):

If a user or your app has a subscription that ends, you will not get a notification. Rather, the subscription purchase will no longer be returned in the list of owned products from the `getPurchases` request to Google. As stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) under the "User Billing" section:

> With In-app Billing Version 3, the failed or expired subscription is
>   no longer returned when you call getPurchases.

If you are using the IabHelper from the TrivialDrive example, this means that the `mPurchaseMap` in the `Inventory` object returned in your `IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener` will not contain a product for the expired subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer to my 1st question. I'm using Transaction.java of AndroidBillingLibrary to get expired state of product.

Comment: Where did you find the Transaction.java? Did you find the answer of the second question?  I am running into same issue